# Generating a Sequential Client Number

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-sql-database

I have a client based system that is needing a sequential client number in the form of the following.

First client would get A001, and then each new client through to A999. Once it hits A999, it would continue to B001-B999, and so on until Z001-Z999, when it would reset to AA001-AA999 and so on through the alphabet.

Does anyone see a way of how this could be achieved?

Comment: How is this related to SQL? do you already have some tables? If so, please add the data

Comment: It's a new database table with no data currently.

Comment: Stored procedure. But why?

Comment: @jarlh - basically a requirement to have a field like this.

Comment: If the client needs it, I'd just use a regular number column, and add a stored procedure to convert the sequence number to your format

Comment: Thanks @YossiVainshtein, but pretty difficult to do that and do the switch over from letter to letter.

Comment: The easiest way I could think of is using `ROW_NUMBER` to filled the leading Characters in one column and using either string concatenation to combine that column with a `Sequence` column.

Comment: Thanks @LONG - might providing an example ?

Comment: Create a table pre-populated with Client Ids and tick them off each time the latest one is assigned

Comment: This is a horrible idea. Don't do this. What happens when you need a new client number and the last one was ASR-999? Not to mention that incrementing a character like that is just a pain to deal with that provides no real benefit. This kind of thing comes up from time to time and it is just awful. Use an identity and save yourself hours of anguish and years of irritation.

Comment: Write some code and show us. We will help you.

Comment: @SeanLange An identity field should never be available to end-users. There's nothing wrong with synthesizing a natural key that meets the customers' needs.

Comment: @nicomp This type of key is no different than an identity. It is easily guessable. And if a value is synthesized it is not a natural key. It is a surrogate key. I have dealt with this "sequential" alphnumeric scheme many times and it is a pain to deal with because you have to be careful. There needs to be an exclusion list so you don't have things like ASS-666. Think of all the three letter words (and abbreviations) that would be pretty awful as a customer number. How about the ones after FUJ? Too many ways to make offensive values for customers like this.

Comment: @SeanLange It's still a natural key because it exists in the customers' problem domain. A SKU is synthesized but it's still a natural key, as is an SSN . By your logic there is no natural key for a database of people short of DNA analysis: every unique identifier of an individual is synthesized.

We, as developers, don't have the freedom to dictate what's potentially 'awful' and what's not to our customers. If they are OK with ASS-666 then we are obligated to support that sequence of characters. We can suggest, but we can't enforce our sensibilities.

Comment: @nicomp - huh??? This is talking about creating a key for the sake of having a key. That by definition is a surrogate key. Just like an identity this would be a surrogate key. It has no meaning outside of the database. A SKU or SSN are potential natural keys (known as candidate keys) because those values have meaning outside of the database.

Comment: And I would contest that at least a part of being a good developer is steering your customer to a good solution. Not just be a sheep and do whatever it is they ask. Often the business asking for these things has not considered all the ramifications and when presented they realize that it was a poor choice.

Comment: @SeanLange "...at least a part of being a good developer is steering your customer to a good solution"  -- I agree. I didn't mean to imply that we should never chime in.

Comment: @SeanLange "This is talking about creating a key for the sake of having a key. " -- That's not how I interpret the OP. It's referred to as a 'client number' which, to me, is a data item that the end-user will see.

Comment: @nicomp You might want to refresh yourself on natural vs surrogate key. Here is the wikipedia entry. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surrogate_key Notice that in their definition it is also known as a "synthetic key"...you even said this is a synthesized value. It doesn't matter if the end user sees this information or not, that doesn't change the fact that it is surrogate key and an identity, or even a guid might be better than incrementing character data.

Comment: @SeanLange "... system-controlled primary keys, or surrogates."  --- Date, C. J. (1993). An introduction to database systems (5th ed., Vol. 1). 596.  Reading, MA: Addison-Wesley.

Comment: @SeanLange "A surrogate key is a unique identifier for a table, often a counter, usually fixed-size, and always system-generated without intelligence, so a surrogate key carries no business meaning."  -- Data Model Scorecard Applying the Industry Standard on Data Model Quality. (2015). Technics Pubns Llc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will give you the exact numbers you asked for from A001 to ZZ999.  If you want more numbers than that you will need to add logic for a third letter, etc.  Note that you aren't getting 1000 numbers per letter, which makes things slightly more awkward.

```
WITH Numbers AS (
    SELECT 1 AS number
    UNION ALL
    SELECT number + 1 AS number FROM Numbers WHERE number < 701298)
SELECT 
    number,
    CASE WHEN number > 25974 THEN CHAR(64 + (number - 1) / 25974) ELSE '' END --This is the first letter (optional)
        + CHAR(65 + ((number - 1) / 999) % 26) --This is the second letter
        + FORMAT(CASE WHEN number < 1000 THEN number ELSE CASE WHEN number % 999 = 0 THEN 999 ELSE number % 999 END END, 'd3') --This is the three digit number
    AS client_id
FROM 
    Numbers 
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);
```

The Numbers CTE is just to get a suitable number of numbers (1 - 701,298).  Once I have them I need to find the boundaries when the second letter changes (every 999 numbers) or the first letter changes (every 26 * 999 = 25974 numbers).  Note that the first letter is suppressed until needed.

This gives you 27 * 26 * 999 client ids (the first letter can be blank or A-Z = so 27 options, the second letter can be A-Z = 26 options, the number can be 001-999 = 999 options).  That's a grand total of 701,298 client ids.

I would suggest either using an `IDENTITY` column, or a `SEQUENCE` to get the "internal" id (which would be a primary key candidate), and then use a function to calculate the client id from this number.  That's safer for multiple users, etc.  You *could* use a calculated column, but that's a pretty big overhead?

Comment: Awesome solution Richard, cheers.  With 701,298 numbers, I don't think it will ever run out. Or at least not for 100 years probably :)

Answer (score 2):

I'd use simple integers as the key and a stored procedure (or calculated column) which translates to your desired format.
I't essentially a numeric operation, check this SQL which calculates the format.

It does assume that you have no more than 2 letters in the beginning, so number of clients is under 26 * 26 * 1000.

```
select tmp.num as client_num, CONCAT(
CASE WHEN tmp.num < 26000 THEN '' ELSE CHAR(ASCII('A') - 1 + (tmp.num / 26000)) END,
CHAR (ASCII('A') + (tmp.num / 1000) % 26),
RIGHT('000'+CAST(tmp.num % 1000 AS VARCHAR(3)),3)) as client_id
from

(select 1 as 'num'
union
select 10
union 
select 150
union 
select 1000
union
select 25999
union 
select 26000
union 
select 27000
union 
select 100000) tmp
```

Returns table:

```
+------------+-----------+
| client_num | client_id |
+------------+-----------+
|          1 | A001      |
|         10 | A010      |
|        150 | A150      |
|       1000 | B000      |
|      25999 | Z999      |
|      26000 | AA000     |
|      27000 | AB000     |
|     100000 | CW000     |
+------------+-----------+
```

Comment: Thanks Yossi, almost right but B000 is invalid, it needed to always start from 001.

Answer (score 0):

EXAMPLE from the comments: (may not be an answer, posted here just because it is long)

```
    CREATE SEQUENCE Numbers 
    INCREMENT BY 1 
    MINVALUE 1
    MAXVALUE 999
    CYCLE
    ;


--DROP TABLE test_DL
      Create table test_DL
    (
     VendorName varchar(50),
     VendorId as LeadingCharacters + CAST(FORMAT(TailingNumbers,'000') as VARCHAR(10)),
     LeadingCharacters VARCHAR(50),
     TailingNumbers INT DEFAULT(NEXT VALUE FOR Numbers),
     [Counter] INT IDENTITY(1,1)
     )

--ALTER SEQUENCE Numbers RESTART WITH 1

DECLARE @CONTROL INT = 0

WHILE (@CONTROL < 250)
BEGIN

INSERT INTO test_DL (VendorName)
VALUES ('THIS'),('IS'),('AN'),('EXAMPLE')

SET @CONTROL = @CONTROL + 1

END

;
WITH CTE
AS
(
SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY [Counter],TailingNumbers) as RowNumber
FROM test_DL
)

UPDATE CTE
SET LeadingCharacters = CASE WHEN RowNumber <= 999 THEN 'A' WHEN 999 < RowNumber AND RowNumber < 2* 999 THEN 'B' END --The MOST ANNOYING PART is here, you need to manually category all the possibles


SELECT * FROM test_DL  --Run this to check the result
```

Above method will be very dumb for future updates. Just give you some ideas lol